# How can I pass command-line arguments to a Perl program?

Tags: perl, command-line

I'm working on a Perl script. How can I pass command line parameters to it?

Example:

```
script.pl "string1" "string2"
```

Comment: Well, first off, you're going to need for it to be `./script.pl` or a whole lotta nothin' will be happening come runtime.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to use the two arguments as input files, you can just pass them in and then use `<>` to read their contents.

If they have a different meaning, you can use `GetOpt::Std` and `GetOpt::Long` to process them easily. `GetOpt::Std` supports only single-character switches and `GetOpt::Long` is much more flexible. From [`GetOpt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html):

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data   = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose;
$result = GetOptions ("length=i" => \$length,    # numeric
                    "file=s"   => \$data,      # string
                    "verbose"  => \$verbose);  # flag
```

Alternatively, `@ARGV` is a special variable that contains all the command line arguments. `$ARGV[0]` is the first (ie. `"string1"` in your case) and `$ARGV[1]` is the second argument. You don't need a special module to access `@ARGV`.

Comment: $ARGV[0] is the first argument; perl counts from 0, and the program name is in $0 not @ARGV.

Comment: @lamcro $ARGV - [`Contains the name of the current file when reading from <> .`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 62):

You pass them in just like you're thinking, and in your script, you get them from the array `@ARGV`.  Like so:

```
my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;
print "thanks, you gave me $numArgs command-line arguments.\n";

foreach my $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {

   print "$ARGV[$argnum]\n";

}
```

From [here](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00001.shtml).

Comment: It's also worth noting that in some programming languages the first (0) argument is the command or script itself... not so in perl though, of course.

Comment: Instead of `$#ARGV + 1` you could also have said `@ARGV`

Comment: just use `ARGV[0]` or `$argv[1]` if you are looking for particular argument.

Answer (score 30):

```
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    print $arg, "\n";
}
```

will print each argument.

Comment: If not using getopts, this is how I would recommend non-destructively traversing an argument list. Based on http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/foreach.html it looks like the syntax is correct; for a caveat, check the section, _Side-effects : The control variable is an alias to the list element_

Answer (score 25):

Yet another option is to use `perl -s`, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

print "value of -x: $x\n";
print "value of -name: $name\n";
```

Then call it like this (as root):

```
./myprog -x -name=Jeff
```

Output:

```
value of -x: 1
value of -name: Jeff
```

Or see [the original article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=33287) for more details.

Comment: If using switches with `-e` you need to add `--` before your switches like `perl -se 'print "got $some\n"' -- -some=SOME`. [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155659/how-do-i-pass-command-line-options-to-a-perl-program-with-perl-e)

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively, a sexier perlish way.....

`my ($src, $dest) = @ARGV;`

"Assumes" two values are passed. Extra code can verify the assumption is safe.

Comment: It is not sexier. All **arguments are available through `@ARGV` without any action from you** just like C/C++ supply them through argv/argc

Answer (score 12):

You can access them directly, by assigning the special variable `@ARGV` to a list of variables.
So, for example:

```
( $st, $prod, $ar, $file, $chart, $e, $max, $flag ,$id) = @ARGV;
```

perl tmp.pl 1 2 3 4 5

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17168769/edit) (it covers answers as well).

Answer (score 7):

If the arguments are filenames to be read from, use the diamond (<>) operator to get at their contents:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
  process_line($line);
}
```

If the arguments are options/switches, use GetOpt::Std or GetOpt::Long, as already shown by slavy13.myopenid.com.

On the off chance that they're something else, you can access them either by walking through @ARGV explicitly or with the `shift` command:

```
while (my $arg = shift) {
  print "Found argument $arg\n";
}
```

(Note that doing this with `shift` will only work if you are outside of all `sub`s.  Within a `sub`, it will retrieve the list of arguments passed to the `sub` rather than those passed to the program.)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
my $output_file;

if ((scalar (@ARGV) == 2) && ($ARGV[0] eq "-i"))
{
    $output_file = chomp($ARGV[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want some values, you can just use the @ARGV array. But if you are looking for something more powerful in order to do some command line options processing, you should use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).