# How to fix Perl warning message when loading gdata package?

Tags: r, windows, perl, xls, gdata

I've updated `Strawberry Perl 64-bit 5.30.2001` and the `gdata` package. Now, when loading `library(gdata)` I always get this warning messages which appear to be related to Perl.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gdata))
# Warning messages:
#   1: In system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :
#     running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ftype perl' had status 2
#   2: In system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :
#     running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ftype perl' had status 2
```

However, `read.xls`, the function I need, seems to run well, except that the warning is repeated every time I use it.

```
read.xls("http://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls")
# trying URL 'http://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls'
# Content type 'application/vnd.ms-excel' length 8704 bytes
# downloaded 8704 bytes

#   X0 First.Name Last.Name Gender       Country Age       Date   Id
# 1  1      Dulce     Abril Female United States  32 15/10/2017 1562
# 2  2       Mara Hashimoto Female Great Britain  25 16/08/2016 1582
# 3  3     Philip      Gent   Male        France  36 21/05/2015 2587
# 4  4   Kathleen    Hanner Female United States  25 15/10/2017 3549
# 5  5    Nereida   Magwood Female United States  58 16/08/2016 2468
# 6  6     Gaston     Brumm   Male United States  24 21/05/2015 2554
# 7  7       Etta      Hurn Female Great Britain  56 15/10/2017 3598
# 8  8    Earlean    Melgar Female United States  27 16/08/2016 2456
# 9  9   Vincenza   Weiland Female United States  40 21/05/2015 6548
# Warning messages:
#   1: In system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :
#     running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ftype perl' had status 2
#   2: In system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :
#     running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ftype perl' had status 2
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this warning because it says nothing to me, I could probably just ignore it and wrap a `suppressWarnings()` around it.

Nevertheless, does anybody know a way to fix this? I couldn't find anything by googling and don't know where to start and what's actually wrong.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gdata_2.18.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2    gtools_3.8.2
```

Comment: sorry just irrelevant question. did you say you updated perl? Because I see the latest perl to be 5.32 on my computer

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, I found Strawberry Perl 64-bit 5.30.2001 as the newest. Would you suggest installing another Perl "distribution", or whatever you call it?

Comment: Could it be the path, on my windows pc it is something like c:/strawberry/perl/bin  (from memory)

Comment: Not really. I use windows, and since I do not want to install many things ie (perl, gcc, grep, python, Rtools, sed, bash, gawk etc) separately, I just installed MSYS2 then no need of installing any of those(even Rtools I dont have to install it)

Comment: just curious thouh. What is the command `c:>ftype perl`??

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, checked the PATH, I have three related entries, `C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin` Could that be an issue?

Comment: @jay.sf; no that looks okay

Comment: @Onyambu I have no idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with a freshly installed version of R, `gdata` and Strawberry Perl.  I finally found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695206/2706569) to a different (but related) question. Adapting the suggestion there, I ran the following on an *elevated* command promt:

```
FTYPE perl=C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe %1 %*
```

This solved the issue for me – however: I am not sure if setting the `FTYPE` like this might have any unwanted side effects. So be careful.

---

Update: The command above *did* suppress the warning "ftype perl' had status 2" for me, but `gdata` still had issues:

> gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by read.xls()
> gdata: to support 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files.
>
> gdata: Run the function 'installXLSXsupport()'
> gdata: to automatically download and install the perl
> gdata: libaries needed to support Excel XLS and XLSX formats.

However, `installXLSXsupport()` failed with an unspecific error message.

I then ran

```
Sys.which("perl")
                              perl 
"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\perl.exe"
```

and realized that the Perl version from RTools takes precedence over my Strawberry Perl installation – and apparently `gdata` does not "like" that Perl version.

Therefore, I decided to give Strawberry Perl precedence over RTools by changing my `.Renviron` file (`usethis::edit_r_environ()`):

```
PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}" # old
PATH="${PATH};${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin" # new
```

Again, I'm not entirely sure what ramifications *this* might have, but it fixed `gdata` for me.
Maybe adjusting the `PATH` alone would also have done the trick (without the `ftype` stunt I made first), but I cannot test this anymore.

What I recommend:

1. Adjust the `PATH` first.
2. If `gdata` still complains about the `ftype`, set the `ftype`.

Comment: Yeah that works!! I followed your suggestion to adjust the `PATH` first, and it seems that this was enough and I didn't need to set the `ftype`.