# How can I manage command line arguments/variables for a script written in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I am trying to manage numerous arguments that are specified by a user when they execute a command. So far, I have been trying to limit my script design to manage arguments as flags that I can easily manage with Getopt::Long as follows:

```
GetOptions ("a" => \$a, "b" => \$b);
```

In this way I can check to see if a or b were specified and then execute the respective code/functions.

However, I now have a case where the user can specify two arguments variables as follows:

```
command -a black -b white
```

This is fine, but I cannot come up with a good way to determine whether -a or -b is specified first. Therefore I do not know whether the argument variable is assigned to `$ARGV[0]` or `$ARGV[1]` after I have executed `GetOptions ("a" => \$a, "b" => \$b);`.

How can I tell which variable is associated with `-a` and which is associated with `-b` in the example above?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program

Comment: I thought `GetOptions` deleted the entries from `ARGV`.

Comment: Nitpick: you shouldn't really use `$a` and `$b` as variables, even in examples; those are Perl's own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getopt supports arguments to options, so you can say for example:

```
GetOptions( 'a=s' => \$a, 'b=s' => \$b);
print "a is $a and b is $b";
```

with the command line in your question prints:

```
a is black and b is white
```

See the [manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) for tons more options. It is a very powerful module.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $a = ''; # option variable with default value (false)
my $b = ''; # option variable with default value (false)

GetOptions ('a' => \$a, 'b' => \$b);

print "a is $a and b is $b\n
```

Please go through the perl documentation of [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). From this doc.

> The call to GetOptions() parses the
>   command line arguments that are
>   present in @ARGV  and sets the option
>   variable to the value 1  if the option
>   did occur on the command line.
>   Otherwise, the option variable is not
>   touched. Setting the option value to
>   true is often called enabling the
>   option.
>
> The option name as specified to the
>   GetOptions() function is called the
>   option specification. Later we'll see
>   that this specification can contain
>   more than just the option name. The
>   reference to the variable is called
>   the option destination.
>
> GetOptions() will return a true value
>   if the command line could be processed
>   successfully. Otherwise, it will write
>   error messages to STDERR, and return a
>   false result.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program) can also help you.