# How do you access function parameters in Perl?

Tags: perl, subroutine

In C++ I would do something like this:

```c++
void some_func(const char *str, ...);
some_func("hi %s u r %d", "n00b", 420);
```

In PHP I would do like this:

```php
function some_func()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
}
some_func($holy, $moly, $guacomole);
```

How do I do that in Perl?

```perl
sub wut {
    # What goes here?
}
```

Comment: There ***must*** be a canonical question from 2008 somewhere for this (*this* question may be the top search engine hit). An even younger one is *[Perl subroutine arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234209/)*. Related (not duplicate): *[Perl Subroutine Prototyping -- The correct way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128918/)*

Comment: Related (but that is for the command-line): *[How can I pass command-line arguments to a Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program)*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You would do:

```
sub wut {
  my @args = @_;
  ...
}
```

Perl automatically populates the special `@_` variable when you call a function. You can access it in multiple ways:

- directly, by simply using `@_` or individual elements within it as `$_[0]`, `$_[1]`, and so on
- by assigning it to another array, as shown above
- by assigning it to a list of scalars (or possibly a hash, or another array, or combinations thereof):

  ```
  sub wut {
    my ( $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, @others ) = @_;
    ...
  }
  ```

Note that in this form you need to put the array `@others` at the end, because if you put it in earlier, it'll slurp up all of the elements of `@_`. In other words, this won't work:

```
sub wut {
  my ( $arg1, @others, $arg2 ) = @_;
  ...
}
```

You can also use `shift` to pull values off of `@_`:

```
sub wut {
  my $arg1 = shift;
  my $arg2 = shift;
  my @others = @_;
  ...
}
```

Note that `shift` will automatically work on `@_` if you don't supply it with an argument.

**Edit:** You can also use named arguments by using a hash or a hash reference. For example, if you called `wut()` like:

```
wut($arg1, { option1 => 'hello', option2 => 'goodbye' });
```

...you could then do something like:

```
sub wut {
  my $arg1 = shift;
  my $opts = shift;
  my $option1 = $opts->{option1} || "default";
  my $option2 = $opts->{option2} || "default2";
  ...
}
```

This would be a good way to introduce named parameters into your functions, so that you can add parameters later and you don't have to worry about the order in which they're passed.

Comment: If you have *many, many* args, you may want to avoid copying them:  `sub wut { for my $arg (@_) { blah blah blah } }`.  Be careful with this, though, because each element in `@_` is an alias to the original argument and you can **change your calling variables**.

Comment: You might also want to mention doing named parameters via `my %args = @_;`