# Trying to pass variable from PHP file to Perl file

Tags: php, perl, variables

I'm trying to pass variable from PHP file to Perl file by this code

In php file:

```
exec("perl delete_all.pl $used");
```

And in perl file I am trying: filename.pl

```
print $used;
```

But it's not  working.

Comment: I think how you used the command line argument is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program   http://www.devdaily.com/perl/perl-command-line-arguments-read-args

Comment: "It's not working" is a bad way to describe your problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114574/encourage-problem-descriptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl isn't seeing `$used`, but the *value* of `$used`:

Get it from the argument list in Perl:

```
$used = $ARGV[0];
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that `$used` will be split up if it has (for instance) spaces in it. It needs suitable escapes added if it might have special characters in it.

Comment: Yep, I was about to edit that in. I don't know much about Perl, truthfully, so I can't say much.