# Perl command-line input parameters

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How can I pass command-line arguments to a Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program)

I have code that parses an input file and outputs a .stat file and a .csv file.  What do I need to code to run my Perl Script from a command prompt like this?

```
perl myprogram.pl -i "C:\temp\inputfile.txt" -o "C:\temp\myoutput.csv" -s "C:\temp\myoutput.stat"
```

Where the -i is the input file (required) and the -o is the output file location for a CSV file (required) and the -s is the output file for a .stat file (optional).  I already have the code for the program but need to implement the arguments so that they can run in command line.

Comment: muh, linked post doesn't mentioned checking for required arguments at all. How is that an exact duplicate???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Getopt::Long qw( GetOptions );

sub usage {
   print STDERR @_ if @_;
   print STDERR ...;
   exit(1);
}

sub help {
   print ...;
   exit(0);
}

my $input_qfn;
my $csv_qfn;
my $output_qfn;

GetOptions(
   "help|h|?" => \&help,
   "i=s"      => \$input_qfn,
   "o=s"      => \$csv_qfn,
   "s=s"      => \$stat_qfn,
) or usage();

defined( $input_qfn )
   or usage("-i option is required\n");
defined( $csv_qfn )
   or usage("-o option is required\n");
```