# add an option to the perl script command line

Tags: perl

assume this is file.txt

```
Name:Lab1:Lab2:Lab3:Lab4:Lab5:Lab6:Exam1:Exam2:Final

Annette Adams :8:24:19:24:10:12:43:35:98
Mary Beard:9:30:19:23:10:14:29:39:87
Antoinette Brown:9:16:18:22:9:12:19:31:79
.
.
.
```

is it possible in `Perl` to write a script with some options which user can pass to command line and get the result.

for example  `getAverage.pl -l 3 file.txt` prints the average of Lab3 Marks.

if it is possible what is the overall process?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for here...  Are you asking if Perl can read the arguments passed to the script or if there is a library for parsing options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass command-line arguments to a Perl program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html  From the documentation:

> The Getopt::Long module implements an extended getopt function called
>   GetOptions(). This function adheres to the POSIX syntax for command
>   line options, with GNU extensions. In general, this means that options
>   have long names instead of single letters, and are introduced with a
>   double dash "--". Support for bundling of command line options, as was
>   the case with the more traditional single-letter approach, is provided
>   but not enabled by default.

For general information about accessing command line options in Perl, read the `perlvar` documentation: [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$ARGV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV)

Answer (score -1):

I put together a quick and dirty solution in python. Should be easy to port it to perl.

```
import sys
lines = open("file.txt",'r').readlines()
if len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[1] == "-l":
    try:
        number = int(sys.argv[2])
    except:
        print "Input a number after the -l switch."

    average = 0

    for i in lines:
        try:
            average += int(i.split(":")[number])
        except:
            pass

    average /= 3

    print "The average score for %s is %d" \
    %(lines[0].split(":")[number], average)

else:
    print "Computer says no."
```

Comment: to me using Getopt::Std is easier