# Pass parameter value with a space to a Perl Script built from a Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a shell script which calls a perl script. The shell script is a wrapper which builds the parameters to be passed to the perl script. The perl script does some code with the given parameters.

The shell script is like this.

```
#!/bin/bash    
value=1
opt2value="someValue"
params="-opt3 someOption"
if [ $value = 1 ] 
then
  params=${params}" -opt4 Y -opt5 \"This is 1\""
elif [ $value = 2 ]
then
  params=${params}" -opt4 Y -opt5 \"This is 2\""
else
  params=${params}" -opt4 N" 
fi
perl -E'say for 0+@ARGV, @ARGV;' -- -opt1 optValue -opt2 ${opt2value} ${params}
```

The Perl Script retrieves all other parameters passed however it only retrieves **"This** for the opt5 parameter and not the whole value passed.

perlScript for retrieving the values

```
use Getopt::Long;
$result = GetOptions(
"opt1=s"  => \$opt1,
"opt2=s"  => \$opt2,
"opt3=s"  => \$opt3,
"opt4=s"  => \$opt4,
"opt5=s"  => \$opt5
}
```

How can I do this. Thanks.

Comment: and then what???????????

Comment: The code is like this.

Comment: sorry bout that. hit the save button too soon

Comment: Are you sure the whole thing `" -option2 Y -option3 \"This is 2\""` is at all getting passed to perl script?

Comment: it is getting passed to the perl script however the value retrieved from option3 is just _"This_. I want it to retrieve _This is 1_

Comment: Can you paste the perl code how you are retrieving the values of arguments?

Comment: @DRTauli you can alos look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program)

Comment: @Anubhab I used the same way for retrieving. edited main question

Comment: Why not forget the shell script and handle the arguments directly from perl ?

Comment: @MiguelPrz I don't want to modify the perl script. I am looking into a solution for bash.

Comment: @Miguel Prz, For starters, there's no way for the Perl script to differentiate `script ... "This is 2"` from `script ... This is 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: `eval`.

More flexible. (Akin to Perl's `system($SHELL_COMMAND)`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
value=1
opt2value="someValue"
params="-opt3 someOption"
if [ "$value" = 1 ]
then
  params="$params -opt4 Y -opt5 \"This is 1\""
elif [ "$value" = 2 ]
then
  params="$params -opt4 Y -opt5 \"This is 2\""
else
  params="$params -opt4 N"
fi
eval "perl -E'say for 0+@ARGV, @ARGV;' -- "\
  "-opt1 optValue -opt2 $opt2value $params"
```

Option 2: Arrays.

Simpler. (Akin to Perl's `system($PROG, @ARGS)`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
value=1
opt2value="someValue"
params=(-opt3 someOption)
if [ "$value" = 1 ]
then
  params=("${params[@]}" -opt4 Y -opt5 "This is 1")
elif [ "$value" = 2 ]
then
  params=("${params[@]}" -opt4 Y -opt5 "This is 2")
else
  params=("${params[@]}" -opt4 N)
fi
perl -E'say for 0+@ARGV, @ARGV;' -- \
  -opt1 optValue -opt2 "$opt2value" "${params[@]}"
```

Output:

```
10
-opt1
optValue
-opt2
someValue
-opt3
someOption
-opt4
Y
-opt5
This is 1
```