# Bash script to tail -f with colored lines

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I tried to create a script from [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8417/5731) like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        tail -f /var/log/mylog.log
fi


if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        tail -f /var/log/mylog.log | perl -pe 's/.*$1.*/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'
fi
```

It shows black tail of the file when I pass no arguments to the script, but every line is red when I pass an argument. I would like it to color only lines which contain the word passed to the script.

For example, this would color lines containing word "info" :

```
./color_lines.sh info
```

How to change the script to work with one argument?

Comment: The single quotes around the Perl script mean that the `$1` in there is interpreted by Perl, not by the shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program), as $ARG[0] but also didn't work as   I expected

Comment: There are at least two parts to that failure: (1) it is `$ARGV[0]` in Perl, and (2) you didn't pass a value to the script to act as `$ARGV[0]`.  You got an appropriate answer from [perreal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390913/perreal), the first of which will work fine as long as there are no spaces in the search pattern (I'd probably use `'s/.*'"$1"'.*/...'` with double quotes around the `$1` to prevent most of those problems).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that would work as well. Should have been an answer ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not quote the argument variable:

```
tail -f input | perl -pe 's/.*'$1'.*/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'
```

You can also use grep for this:

```
tail -f input | grep -e $1 -e ''  --color=always
```

and to color the whole line with grep:

```
tail -f input | grep -e ".*$1.*" -e ''  --color=always
```

Comment: Thanks. Was so simple. BTW your grep example will only color the word, not whole line.