# Data retrieval from Java to Perl script

Tags: perl

I run a process from Java to run a Perl script as follows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl","C:\\Perl\\bin\\try.pl", "uname=test"});
```

How can I get the data in Perl script. I tried the following, `$uname`, `@uname`, `${uname}`.

Can anybody suggest any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access named command line arguments like that in Perl. The arguments get passed in using the special variable @ARGV, which you can either use directly, or manipulate using a module that provides additional functionality.

If you don't care about having named arguments, then if you have the following Java call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl","C:\\Perl\\bin\\try.pl", "test"});
```

Then the following Perl snippet should work:

```
print "First argument is: $ARGV[0]\n";
print "The argument is, indeed, 'test'!\n" if ($ARGV[0] eq 'test');
```

On the other hand, if you do need named arguments, then you'll want to look into a module that provides such functionality. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program) suggest [GetOpt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), for instance.