# Data retrieval from Perl to Java

Tags: perl

Currently, I am reading some data from Perl, I want to retrieve messages from Perl for each and every step. I tried using this code,

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl","C:\\Perl\\bin\\try.pl", "uname=test"});
 BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
 String s = reader.readLine();
  System.out.println("perl said [ " + s + " ]");
```

My perl script as follows,

```
$path_to_file = $ARGV[0] or die("argument not passed") ;
print "success";
# some code
```

If I dont receive any argument, then we need to retrieve the message, that there is no argument passed. like that I want log all the information. I tried giving print data. That is working. But if the argument is not passed. I want the data that argument not passed.

is it possible to retrieve?

Comment: So you are [passing messages between Perl and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875289/data-retrieval-from-java-to-perl-script), I see, interesting.

Comment: Looks like you asked this exact question 6 hours ago, and got an answer. An answer which you accepted and commented "thanks it works". So, what's with the new question?

Comment: You might be interested in sending serialized data, using the JSON module in Perl.

Comment: The previous question was to send the data from java to perl and that is success. Now the question is when running a process, how get the activities from perl back to java. I think you better understand. Please see back the question, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875289/data-retrieval-from-java-to-perl-script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hereby found the answer for my above question,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl","C:\\Perl\\bin\\try.pl", "uname=test"});
BufferedReader readError = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    s = readError.readLine();
     System.err.println("perl said [ " + s + " ]");
```

By this way i capture the error details. Thanks for all your suggestions. Also, i changed my perl script as follows,

```
my $path_to_file = $ARGV[0] or   {print " Argument not passed! " };
```

Comment: Nice on you for coming back and posting the answer. I don't know enough Java to comment on that part, but in the Perl part you can also instead do `my $path_to_file; if (@ARGV) { $path_to_file = $ARGV[0]; } else { print "Argument not passed"; }` which allows you to do more in the else part while keeping the code neat. And if you want the value passed to uname, you can do `my ($left, $right) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $path_to_file)` within the `if` part, then the value (the string "test" in this case) will be in `$right`.

Comment: Btw does this code you posted actually work? It looks like you are reading from ErrorStream in Java but printing to normal output in Perl, you should try using `die` instead of `print` if this doesn't work. `die` has two effects: it prints the output to standard error output instead of the normal output, and it terminates the script (which I'm assuming you want).

Comment: Actually, i capture the error in catch part of java side and also for each and every error i don't want my work to stop. some part i want to capture, but some part even if there are error, i want to continue. That's why i use print instead of die. And also, above is just some example. I am actually doing some other process with java and perl.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it in unnecessarily complicated ways... If you speak Tamil, feel free to drop a mail to my email id (it's in my profile), I'd be glad to help out a fellow Perler.