# How do I pass command line options to a Perl program with perl -e?

Tags: bash, perl

I want to pass command line options that start with a dash (`-` or `--`) to a Perl programm I am running with the `-e` flag:

```
$ perl -E 'say @ARGV' -foo
Unrecognized switch: -foo  (-h will show valid options).
```

Passing arguments that don't start with a `-` obviously work:

```
$ perl -E 'say @ARGV' foo
foo
```

**How do I properly escape those so the program reads them correctly?**

I tried a bunch of variations like `\-foo`, `\\-foo`, `'-foo'`, `'\-foo'`, `'\\-foo'`. None of those work though some produce different messages. `\\-foo` actually runs and outputs `\-foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-s`, like:

```
perl -se 'print "got $some\n"' -- -some=SOME
```

the above prints:

```
got SOME
```

From the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> -s   enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command
>   line after the program name but before any
>               filename arguments (or before an argument of --).  Any switch found there is removed from @ARGV and sets
>               the corresponding variable in the Perl program.  The following program prints "1" if the program is
>               invoked with a -xyz switch, and "abc" if it is invoked with -xyz=abc.
>
> ```
>             #!/usr/bin/perl -s
>             if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }
>
>         Do note that a switch like --help creates the variable "${-help}", which is not compliant with "use strict
>         "refs"".  Also, when using this option on a script with warnings enabled you may get a lot of spurious
>         "used only once" warnings.
> ```

For the simple arg-passing use the `--`, like:

```
perl -E 'say "@ARGV"' -- -some -xxx -ddd
```

prints

```
-some -xxx -ddd
```

Comment: Actually I only want the `--`. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: I don't need the parsing, I just need them to go through to the program.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `--` before the flags that are to go to the program, like so:

```
  perl -e 'print join("/", @ARGV)' -- -foo bar
```

prints

```
  -foo/bar
```