# Replace multi-line plain text

Tags: perl, sed, replace, yaml

Assuming you have plenty of yaml files (or anything similar) and you want to add a description to all objects with a given name, e.g.

```
- name: alan
  age: 8

- name: britney # some comment about britney
  hobbies: ["painting", "CS"]
  age: 21

- name: charles # some comment about charles
                # that spans over multiple lines
  age: 42
```

And I have a list of objects with names that require a description, e.g.

```
britney: teamblue
charles: foobar
```

How can I add a line with a description to reach the following:

```
- name: alan
  age: 8

- name: britney # some comment about britney
  hobbies: ["painting", "CS"]
  age: 21
  description: teamblue

- name: charles # some comment about charles
                # that spans over multiple lines
  age: 42
  description: foobar
```

So far I go pretty close but I keep failing at replacing a multiline plain text with another:

```
s=$(awk "/${name}/" RS= ./*.yml)
r=$(awk "/${name}/" RS= ./*.yml && echo "  description: ${desc}")
```

I need to somehow look for `$s` and replace it with `$r` and I cannot make it work. I tried multiple variations of the following two:

```
sed "s/$s/$r/" ./*.yml
perl -i -0pe "s/$s/$r/" ./*.yml
```

But somehow the special characters (newlines, double quotes, ...) in the yaml break them and I either get an error message like `unterminated substitute pattern` or the output is the same and nothing was matched.

Also maybe relevant for `sed`, I'm using macOS.

Comment: Use a YAML parser.

Comment: Using a parser, I guess I would lose all comments and formatting in the files.

Comment: Which formatting? YAML is a machine-readable format. The formatting doesn't matter. There should be a parser that understands comments I believe. Someone with more YAML knowledge will come along shortly I am sure. But doing this without a parser means you have to build your own parser.

Comment: Why is the line moved down with `hobbies`?

Comment: I don't agree, I don't need a parser, I just need to replace plain text. It's that simple: I have some multi-line input text with special characters, and I need to replace it with some other multi-line text with special characters. And I don't need regexp or a parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361752/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-perl-program <--I think you need to be using this approach rather than trying to use bash variables directly in your regex..if I'm understanding what you're doing.

Comment: @ATN, Re "*I don't need a parser*", By definition, you need a parser. What you are trying to write is a parser. The problem is that the parser you are writing is horrible at it. Worse, you imply this is hand-written YAML, so the user could provide any legitimate YAML, and none of the provided answers come even close to doing that. Did you know that valid JSON is valid YAML?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    sub(/:/,"",$1)
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
$3 in map {
    $0 = $0 "\n  description: " map[$3]
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk list RS= ORS='\n\n' foo.yaml
- name: alan
  age: 8

- name: britney # some comment about britney
  hobbies: ["painting", "CS"]
  age: 21
  description: teamblue

- name: charles # some comment about charles
                # that spans over multiple lines
  age: 42
  description: foobar
```

The above used these input files:

```
$ cat list
britney: teamblue
charles: foobar
```

.

```
$ cat foo.yaml
- name: alan
  age: 8

- name: britney # some comment about britney
  hobbies: ["painting", "CS"]
  age: 21

- name: charles # some comment about charles
                # that spans over multiple lines
  age: 42
```

Comment: @ghoti: That is completely irrelevant to the question. Why would anyone want to read about your lunch?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($3":" in a){sub(/$/,"\n  description: "a[$3":"])}1' list RS= ORS="\n\n" file.yaml
```

`FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}` : While reading file `list`, create an associative array `a` with keys as `$1` and values as `$2`. Eg. `a[britney:]=teamblue`

`($3":" in a){sub(/$/,"\n  description: "a[$3":"])}1` : While reading file `file.yaml`, if `$3":"` is a key in `a` then append `description` in the record before printing.

**Output**

```
- name: alan
  age: 8

- name: britney # some comment about britney
  hobbies: ["painting", "CS"]
  age: 21
  description: teamblue

- name: charles # some comment about charles
                # that spans over multiple lines
  age: 42
  description: foobar
```

Comment: awk like this is the reason I can sleep at night.

Comment: @zzxyz: Sorry I didn't get.  Is it a compliment or opposite ? :P

Comment: a compliment :)  This is really slick.